# AWS publish incremental, exclude some folders on server

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are using AWS explorer to publish our website changes from Visual studio to our Elastic beanstalk instances in Amazon. We are using "Deploy application incrementally" which is nice.

the only issue is, when we publish, all the extra folders which are not part of the deployment package will be removed. I have some folders that should be on the website root on the server.
i dont want amazon publish to touch these folders. Is there anyway i can specify this exclusion some where.

Your inputs will greatly help in saving our time. thanks in advance.